# removing space from string in python

Tags: python, string, space

```
def digits_plus(test):

   test=0
   while (test<=3):

       print str(test)+"+",
       test = test+1


   return()

digits_plus(3)
```

The output is: 
0+  1+  2+  3+

However i would like to get: 0+1+2+3+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method to do that would be to create a list of the numbers and then join them.

```
mylist = []

for num in range (1, 4):
    mylist.append(str(num))
```

we get the list [1, 2, 3]

```
print '+'.join(mylist) + '+'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck using Python 2.7, start your module with

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Then instead of

```
print str(test)+"+",
```

use

```
print(str(test)+"+", end='')
```

You'll probably want to add a `print()` at the end (out of the loop!-) to get a new-line after you're done printing the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `sys.stdout` object to write output (to stdout) that you have more fine control over. This should let you output exactly and only the characters you tell it to (whereas print will do some automatic line endings and casting for you)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

test = '0'

sys.stdout.write(str(test)+"+")

# Or my preferred string formatting method:
# (The '%s' implies a cast to string)
sys.stdout.write("%s+" % test)

# You probably don't need to explicitly do this, 
# If you get unexpected (missing) output, you can 
# explicitly send the output like
sys.stdout.flush()
```